# Similarity Measure for small strings

Tags: clustering, similarities

I am looking for a good similarity measure to conflate entries of a column (Product Brand in my scenario)

Text like : ("Dell", "Dell Laptops"), ("ACP","ACP by XYZ"),("Acer Notebooks","Acer Laptops"),etc

I have of list of these values,

Currently I have only implemented simple edit distance to conflate entries like ("Lenovo",Lanovo").

Would like to add more similarity measures to conflate similar entries.

Comment: Such as Levenshtein?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I am using Levenshtein to detect entries where the words/strings are almost same. I want a approach to catch 'Acer Laptop' and 'Acer'.
Hope I am able to explain what i am looking for

Comment: I'm not sure this is a generic enough problem then. I doubt there will be a lot of published work on this, it's too specific. But modifying Levenshtein to make appends/prepends cheaper than changes within the string should do the trick.

Comment: That will only partially take care of the problem, thanks anyway, i'll implement this atleast.

Comment: Well, unless you can be more specific, it will be hard to provide more advice. If you open this up to wide, Trend Micro is nearly the same as Microsoft; but this is not based on any theoretical foundation, it is purely a domain decision.

Comment: It is okey if Trend Micro and Microsoft are flagged as similar. This is only the preliminary phase of getting similar pairs and I later, based on other features do the final call to mark them as same or diffrent